# Stylishing the anchor tag that provides the link for the currently targeted section ("some_url#section") of the page

Tags: css, css-selectors

With pure CSS, is it possible to select a link whose href attribute matches the current URL anchor without having its `id` attribute equivalent to its `href`?

For example, if the user is at the section `#abc` of the main page (`index.html#abc`), I'd like to set some CSS rules for that link whose `href` is `#abc`, but only when the user has the URL pointing to that `#abc` section.

Like, for the following HTML:

```
<a href="#abc">Some link</a>
<a href="#other">Other link</a>
...
more unrelated tags
...
<div id="other">...</div>
<div id="abc">...</div>
```

I'd like to know whether it's possible, with pure CSS and no Javascript, to set styles for the link whose `href` is #abc, but only when the element whose `id` is also "abc" is the targeted one by the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possible way I know of for CSS to know what URL is currently used.

The only possible (hacky) way is to place the element below the sections and abuse the `:hover` and `~` selector. But, to be honest, JavaScript is invented for a reason.

But this also doesn't really match your current question.

```css
#goodbye:hover ~ nav a[href*="#goodbye"], #hello:hover ~ nav a[href*="#hello"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: cyan;
}

/* other styling */
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 105vh;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#hello {
  background: lightgrey;
}

#goodbye {
  background: salmon;
}

nav {
  height: 5vh;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="hello">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <a href="#hello">hello</a>
  <a href="#goodbye">Goodbye</a>
</section>

<section id="goodbye">
  <h1>Goodbye</h1>
  <a href="#hello">hello</a>
  <a href="#goodbye">Goodbye</a>
</section>

<nav>
  <a href="#hello">hello</a>
  <a href="#goodbye">Goodbye</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes, the use of Javascript is not allowed because the site should work well even when it's off. I appreciate your answer anyway.